# How to Get selected values from select values in PHP?

Tags: php, html

I have a html form which have a select list box from which you can select any one value. Consider form method is post method. The html code for form is as follows.

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="particular_order.php?OrderId=<?php echo $Order_no; ?>" >
<?php
    //$Order_no=$_GET['OrderId'];
    $result =  mysql_query("select Menu_Item_Name, Menu_Item_id, Menu_Item_quantity,Menu_Item_Price,PreparationStatus from order_details where order_id='$Order_no' && status!='C' ");
    $rows_count = mysql_num_rows($result);

    $i=0;
    $ItemName="";
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        if($i==0)
        {
            echo "<table id='table1' style='WIDTH: 400px;' border='3' cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=3 width=693 align=center>
                <tbody>";
            echo "<tr><td><font color='#0000e' size='2'><strong>Item Name</strong></font></td>
                <td><font color='#0000e' size='2'><strong>Item Id</strong></font></td>
                <td><font color='#0000e' size=2><strong>Quantity</strong></font></td>
                <td><font color='#0000e' size=2><strong>Price</strong></font></td>
                <td><font color='#0000e' size=2><strong>Status</strong></font></td></tr>";
        }
        if($row['PreparationStatus']=='NEW')
            $ps='READY';
        else
            $ps='NEW';
        $ItemId=$row['Menu_Item_id'];
        echo $ItemName;
        echo"<tr>
            <td><font color='#0000e' size='2'>".$row['Menu_Item_Name']."</font></td>
            <td><font color='#0000e' size='2'>".$row['Menu_Item_id']."</font></td>
            <td><font color='#0000e' size='2'>".$row['Menu_Item_quantity']."</font></td>
            <td><font color='#0000e' size='2'>".$row['Menu_Item_Price']."</font></td>
            <td><SELECT NAME='Select2[]' id='PrepStatus' onChange=updatePrepStatus('$Order_no','$ItemId','$ps')><OPTION VALUE='NEW'><font color='#0000e' size='2'>".$row['PreparationStatus']."
                </OPTION><OPTION VALUE='READY'><font color='#0000e' size='2'>$ps</OPTION></SELECT>&nbsp;</font></td></tr>";
        $i++;
    }

    if($i==0)
    {
        echo "<p align='center'>NO RECORDS<strong><font color='white' size='3'>";
    } 
    else
    {
        echo "</tbody></table></p>
            <input value='Submit' type='submit' name='submit'>";  
    }
?>
</form>
```

I want to display the selected values in select list box on same php page.
But the selected values are not getting accessed correctly.

```
<?php  
  $arr=$_POST['Select2'];
      for($i=0;$i<sizeof($arr);$i++)
         echo $arr[$i];
?>
```

Comment: Can you post the output?

Comment: Why are you naming your select as an array in your HTML when you only have one of them? `sizeof($arr)` is always going to be `1`.

Comment: What do you expect to get and what do you actually get?  Also, your HTML uses several deprecated tags and attributes, you should look at removing things like `<font>` elements, using `<th>` instead of `<td>` where appropriate, using `<label>` and removing appearance attributes like `cellspacing` and `border` from your `<table>` element and using CSS instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code, and I observe and must assume that the values of the selects are being passed/posted correctly by the form and browser/client.

Only the selected VALUES of selects will be posted.

I noticed that you are leaving the labels to the first select options as blank but assigning those same options the value of "NEW" and then you are labeling the options with value of "READY" with the label of "NEW" ... Was that intended? I would think you meant to label NEW with NEW and READY with a blank?

Comment: Thanx all !! I got it fixed like this...  <td><SELECT NAME='Select2[]' id='PrepStatus' onChange=updatePrepStatus('$Order_no','$ItemId','$ps')><OPTION VALUE=".$row['PreparationStatus']."><font color='#0000e' size='2'>".$row['PreparationStatus']."                          </OPTION><OPTION VALUE='$ps'><font color='#0000e' size='2'>$ps</OPTION></SELECT>&nbsp;</font></td></tr>";

Comment: Actually i was keeping the OPTION VALUE as fixed(NEW and READY)  ...but it is required to change the OPTIONS according  to database values...and when otpions are changed using the select box and sumbit is done ...then those shud be given as o/p in php.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should actually review your code, since it contains many errors and it might cause further errors. Assuming that the code is rendered correctly, I do have a few suggestions:

- If the select is not going to allow selecting multiple options, you should name it just "Select2", so you'd have the selected value in $POST['Select2']. If you want to allow multiple option selection, you should add the multiple="multiple" attribute to your select.
- If after reviewing the code and the select field it still doesn't work, you should debug your script, or try to dump the $_POST variable if can't debug, to check if "Select2" is in $_POST.

Anyway, I would advice you to review your code and use some kind of themplate to render the HTML.